# How to pass variable from template to view in Flask?

Tags: flask

For example: every user of app have some points and they are saved in database (of course)

When user comes to page /profile, template shows `{{ points }}` to him.

But I want to reduce some user points (10 for example) if he clicks a button. I think this should look like:

Template.html:

```
Your points: {{ current_user.points }} <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}" button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="reduce">Reduce it!</button></a>
```

But how can I get pass signal "reduce" to view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got all the information you need.  You know which user clicked the link from the `current_user` proxy (I'll assume you're using flask-login or flask-security because of that).  So the route that's the target of the submission just needs to fetch that users points from the database, adjust it, and commit it.

If you're using something like Flask-Sqlalchemy it could just be:

```
@login_required
@app.route('/reduce/')
def reduce_points():
    current_user.points -= 10
    db.session.commit()
    return 'Points Reduced!'
```

With the template rendering the link to `{{ url_for('reduce_points') }}`.

Lets say you instead wanted one view, that handled a few different actions-- you could have a form for each button, that included the action you wanted:

```
<form method='post' target="{{ url_for('actions') }}">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="reduce"/>
<input type="submit" value="Reduce!"/>
</form>
```

Then your app's route code could just look for a form element called action-- then use logic based of it's value to decide what to do.  Also read up on CSRF protection (Flask-WTF gives it to you for free) if you're handling forms, saves a user accidently clicking the button a few times and zeroing out their account.